# How to choose when to loop through listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, loops

I have a listbox of items that I want to go through one by one and each item should be printed in a messagebox. I want to by default, when it reaches the end of the listbox, to just stop. But if I check my checkbox "Loop through list [x]" I want it to continue and just start over when it reaches the bottom. How can I do that?

This is my code right now to loop through it.

```
int i = 0;
i = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
i = i + 1;
if (i > listBox1.Items.Count - 1)
i = 0;
listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
MessageBox.Show("Item: " + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

This never ends though, it just continues to loop. How can I make a check that if it's on the bottom it just stops? This should be my code if I checked the box "Loop through list [x]"...

This is all in my Timer1 with Interval 5000ms

edit: Also, how can I make it print like "You have reached the end of the list!" when it comes to the bottom of the listbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that is all in "Timer1", which means the code actually looks like:

```
private void TimerElapsed(...)
{
    int i = 0;
    i = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    i = i + 1;
    if (i > listBox1.Items.Count - 1)
    i = 0;
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
    MessageBox.Show("Item: " + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

When you reach the end, you set i = 0, which just allows the loop to continue without throwing. To stop the loop, you need to stop the timer invoking this function as well.

The correct code would be:

```
private void TimerElapsed(...)
{
    int i = 0;
    i = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    i++;
    if (i > listBox1.Items.Count - 1)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("End of list reached!");
       if (LoopAfterEnd)
          i = 0;
       else
          Timer1.Stop();
    }
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
    MessageBox.Show("Item: " + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

It could also be written:

```
private void TimerElapsed(...)
{
    int i = 0;
    i = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    i++;
    if (i > listBox1.Items.Count - 1)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("End of list reached!");
       i = 0;
       if (!LoopAfterEnd)
          Timer1.Stop();
    }
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
    MessageBox.Show("Item: " + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Which has the advantage of letting you restart the loop later by just starting the timer again!

Comment: I see! Thanks! But also check my "edit" in my question. How can I make it print something when it reaches the end of the list? EDIT: Saw your edit now, thanks!

Comment: See my update (I was wrong about "i" scope since you assign it to selected index. This is a really bad choice of variable name, since it is so often used as an iteration variable).

Comment: The message box code I wrote would be kind of weird, since reaching the end would pop two message boxes at the same time. Let me know if you need me to change it, otherwise I'll leave fixing it as an exercise to you!

Comment: I just don't understand one thing, it's the (LoopAfterEnd), why do I need a loop after the end? And what could that be for example. Anything like if (1 == 1)?

Comment: That was a made up variable :) It was meant to represent the checkbox state from the checkbox in your example. Probably something like: `if (loopCheckbox.Checked)` would work. Sorry for the confusion! Also, notice what is in the "true" condition for that check. It sets "i" to 0, allowing the loop to continue. The else stops the timer, stopping the loop.